# What am I supposed to type as user name and password for localhost in IIS Manager?

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-manager

I'm trying to connect to default web site on localhost – but IIS asks me for credentials (I know I can use an Administrator account, but I'm trying to log on when IIS is not run as an Administrator). I tried putting in the administrator user name and password for windows, but it doesn't accept them.

I'm using windows 7 home premium.

What should I enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok - so anonymous is enabled. The next thing to check is that the identity the website is running under has access to the website folder. Each site in IIS runs in an application pool, and each pool runs under a user account. So first find out what app pool you're running under. On the right hand side click on Advanced Properties and check the name of you application pool. Then close that window and double click on application pools above your website on the left. Click on the app pool your site is running under, and then click advanced properties on the right. In the dialog box that launches, under process model check the value of Identity. Then go check the permissions on your website folder and make sure that identity has a minimum of read and execute rights on the folder.

Added another answer as the text above exceeds the comment limit

Comment: If you set it to LocalSystem it should work :). LocalSystem should be one of the values in the drop down.

Comment: Didn't help either. Nor did the code from http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/management/authentication/credentials . So I just gave up. Thanks a lot for all the very clear help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set your identity for a site to run under then you either need to run it as the local system account or you need to create a new user account on the machine and use those credentials.

Comment: Are you setting up the website or opening it in a browser?

Comment: I created a website in VWD and now would want to connect to it through IIS Manager, just as I do when running as administrator, and just as I do to a website I have on a web hosting server.

Comment: ok then if you open up IIS Manager and double click on Authentication, is Anonymous Authentication enabled?

Comment: I don't see an authentication button, only the useless start page.

Comment: OK. I logged on as administrator - Anonymous authentication _is_ enabled.

Comment: Don't browse to the site - go into Ctrl Panel -> IIS Manager. Then click on your default web site on the left, then in Features View on the right you should have an Authentication icon under IIS. If you don't have any of this then you need to install IIS 7 Manager from Add/Remove Windows Features

Comment: See my last comment - I did get to that through an Administrator account. And Anonymous authentication _is_ enabled. What now?